# I Have created Exe Using Pyinstaller.How to bundle Cx_racle into this

Tags: python-3.x

My Script is having import cx_oracle where it is connecting to Oracle DB and doing some action. I have created exe for Windows machine using pyinstaller and tried to achieve same in my machine it is working properly. When I tried in another machine without installing python it is throwing an error like below.
Please help how can I overcome this issue.
Error:

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "The specified module could not be found". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#windows for help
[1856] Failed to execute the script
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Finally after long time trial and error. Found the resolution.
the machine where you want to run the stand-alone application that is using cx_Oracle please follow below steps for windows:
1.Download the instant client form the below URL.
 https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html.
2. Unzip it and copy the path set it in Environment Variable.
3. After this, I have executed exe its worked fine foe me.